# Norton equivalent theorem

Tags: norton

1. In norton equivalent theorem I don't get how I = in (I can be equivalent to in)[image]
2. Also I don't get how iN can be 2A 
   How can I get iN?
   [image]

""edit:**
Then how come this In is 1A? What is the difference between question 2?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- If there is a short-circuit between *a* and *a'* then all the current will take that route in preference to the parallel route with resistance.
- Since your current source is pushing out 2 A then all of it will flow through the short-circuit so \$ i_N = 2 \ \mathrm A \$.

---

From comments:

> Why do all the current take the a-a' route in preference to parallel route with resistance?

**Quick answer**: because it's easier.

**Longer answer**: to get current to flow through a resistor you need some voltage across it. By definition you can't have voltage across a short circuit¹, therefore you won't have voltage across the resistor and can't push any current through it².

---

¹ A short-circuit has resistance = 0. Voltage across it is given by Ohm's Law, \$ V = IR = I \times 0 = 0 \$ no matter what the current is.

² Again, from Ohm's Law, \$ I = \frac {V}{R} = \frac {0}{R} = 0 \$ through any resistance in parallel with a short circuit.

Comment: Why do all the current take the a-a' route in preference to parallel route with resistance?

Comment: See the update.

Comment: I added a little mathematical "proof" which may help further.